# counting common words in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def words(word,number):
    if number<len(word):
        result={}
        for key,value in word.items():
            common_num=sorted(set(word.values()), reverse=True)[:number]
            if value in common_num:
                result.update({key:value})
        word.clear()
        word.update(result)
        new_word_count={}
        common_word=[]
        common=[]
        for key, value in word.items():
            if value in common_word:
                common.append(value)
            common_word.append(value)
        new_word_count=dict(word)
        for key,value in new_word_count.items():
            if value in common:
                del word[key]
```

Example:

```
>>> word={'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c' : 3, 'd: 3, 'e': 4, 'f' : 4, 'g' : 5}
>>> words(word,3)
```

My output: {'g': 5}

Expected output:{'g': 5, 'e': 4, 'f': 4}

Any idea why im getting this output

Comment: my program should take 5,4,4 as the highest numbers, but its taking 5,4,3

Comment: Is this a homework assignment that must be solved a certain way? Otherwise, I'd suggest letting `collections.Counter` do most of the work.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes it's an assignment and i cant use collections.Counter

Comment: Huh? You passed it a `dict` with 5, 4, 4, so why do you expect/want it to be 5, 4, 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, without any special imports, there are easier ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. You've got a whole lot of rigmarole involved in tracking and storing the values being kept, then deleting, then re-adding, when you could simplify a lot; even with explanatory comments, this is substantially shorter:

```
def common_words(word_count, number):
    # Early out when no filtering needed
    if number >= len(word_count):
        return

    # Get the top number+1 keys based on their values
    top = sorted(word_count, key=word_count.get, reverse=True)[:number+1]

    # We kept one more than we needed to figure out what the tie would be
    tievalue = word_count[top.pop()]

    # If there is a tie, we keep popping until the tied values are gone
    while top and tievalue == word_count[top[-1]]:
        top.pop()

    # top is now the keys we should retain, easy to compute keys to delete
    todelete = word_count.keys() - top
    for key in todelete:
        del word_count[key]
```

There are slightly better ways to do this that avoid repeated lookups in `word_count` (sorting `items`, not `keys`, etc.), but this is easier to understand IMO, and the extra lookups in `word_count` are bounded and linear, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: Blech. Blue screen knocked me out before I replied: You're right about the problem (it happens whenever the top value occurs `number+1` times or more), but fix is trivial, just changing `while tievalue == word_count[top[-1]]:` to `while top and tievalue == word_count[top[-1]]:`. Already updated in answer.

Comment: I won't delete the answer, but the basic logic here is fairly straightforward. If you haven't had certain concepts introduced (e.g. the `set`-like behaviors of `dict` views), you'd need to reimplement them with the tools you have available. Or you can preserve some of the logic you had, use `top` to make a new `dict` containing the values to keep, then `clear` and `update` `word_count` the way you were doing before. The same basic logic has many variations; you can and should play around with it, not just to fool graders looking for copying, but to be sure you understand what's happening.

Comment: @CAVS: It's not good form to deface the question just because you have an answer. Your original code is wrong in any event, so it's not like you need to worry about people copying it and getting you in trouble; once you fix it, it shouldn't be a clear duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Although in the comments the author mentions avoiding `Counter()`, for those interested in seeing how to apply it, here is a short solution as suggested by @ShadowRanger:

```
import collections as ct

word={'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c' : 3, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f' : 4, 'g' : 5}
words = ct.Counter(word)
words.most_common(3)
# [('g', 5), ('f', 4), ('e', 4)]
```